# Decouple PyCharm editor scheme and GUI theme

Tags: pycharm, darkmode

There are 2 options in PyCharm to set the environment colors:

- For the GUI: `Appearance & Behaviour > Appearance > UI Options > Theme`
- For the editor component: `Editor > Colors & Fonts > Scheme`

I changed the latter to a dark theme, and got a dialog asking me if I wanted to change it for the UI as well - with an additional box to not ask me again. I checked the box and clicked yes. Subsequently, every time I change one of the options, the other one changes as well.

I changed my mind and want to have them separate: How can I decouple these options again?

Using PyCharm 2017.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change this setting by editing the value in the file `%USER%\\.PyCharmCE2017.1\config\options\options.xml`

```xml
<property name="change.laf.on.editor.theme.change" value="false" />
```